# Simplemodal - How to implement it?

Tags: forms, simplemodal, contacts

Newbie here...easy question for you pro outthere

How to put a button on a htmlpage that says E-mail here, and then the simplemodal contactform pop up (just like in the demo)
Can't get it right with the link... :(

Regards
/Pia

Answer (score 0):

Posting your code (HTML and JS) would be helpful here as the examples are pretty clear for a simple situation like this, so it's hard to know what you're doing wrong.

Check the following:

1. That your script tags are in this
   order: JQuery, SimpleModal, JS file
   that contains the modal-open binding
2. That you are binding to the right
   div in your html with $('#id').modal()
   preferably - $('.class').modal() might work,
   but binding by id is best

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the [contact form demo](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/#contact-form) and using the code in the index file as an example of how to do it?

Comment: Hi Eric, yes I've tried that, but don't know how to get the right path. My index.html file is outside the contactfolder (see image). Image: http://www.sminket.se/image.jpg Thanks for helping me. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. You need to adjust the paths to images, js, css, etc. to work with your structure.